# Its possible to sync two instances, one playing mp4 and another m3u8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vlc, libvlc, m3u8

With Python, its possible to open two VLC instances and sync beetwen them?

Scenario:
A two hours movie on first instance, a playlist–m3u8 on second instance.
User forward the movie and second instance goes foward to another segment on playlist.

Comment: If you can get the durations of the items in the playlist, you can calculate the playlist index and the offset in the item that aligns with the offset in the movie. Then it comes down to writing a listener that reacts to the current play position in the movie and seeks in the playlist if the two are too far out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a feature provided out of the box. You will need to hack this together yourself.